# Android Studio - Save Preview Settings

Tags: android, api, android-studio, configuration, settings

Does anyone know if its possible to save the settings you make when you are adjusting the Device and API? Every time I launch Android Studio I am having to change the Device and move the API down to API 21 so that the rendering error goes away.

Comment: how/where do you adjust those settings? I would recommend adjusting those settings in the corresponding build.gradle. This overrides the AndroidManifest.xml and also can be versioned in the VCS.